# Social media icons are not coming on one line even after using display:inline-block

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I have a WordPress site https://dmarketer.com/ I want to show social icons in a one line but they are displayed vertically even after using:

```
display:inline-block;
```

```css
.social {
       margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .social h4 {
       margin-top: 25px;
       font-size: 15px;
    }

    .social a i {
      padding: 0px !important;
      background: transparent !important;
      font-size: 46px !important;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .fa-facebook-square {
      color: #4267b2;
    }

    .fa-facebook-square:hover {
      color: #365899;
    }

    .fa-twitter-square {
      color: #1da1f2;
    }

    .fa-twitter-square:hover {
      color: #1da1da;
    }

    .fa-linkedin-square {
      color: #0084bf;
    }

    .fa-linkedin-square:hover {
       color: #0073b1;
    }

    .fa-instagram {
      color: #d9317a;
    }

    .fa-instagram:hover {
      color: #bc318f;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social">
        <h4>Connect with me on below social channels:</h4>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/RealMahadev/" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fb"></i>
    </a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/realmahadev" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
    </a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/realmahadev" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i>
    </a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/realmahadev/" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-instagram instagram"></i>
    </a>
    </div>
```

I am using Font-Awsome icons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `<br>` tags between those links that contain the icons.

Comment: You are right! I have minified HTML code and removed `<br>` tags. Could you help me with one more problem. On my site, I have Recommended Tools Widget, I made its position fixed using WordPress plugin. When I scroll my site to the bottom, it overlaps with footer. How should I prevent this??

Comment: that `fixed` parameter and its position settings are added automatically by a javascript, which also adds a `bottom` parameter when scrolling reaches the end of the page. You would have to adapt that `bottom` value in the script of the plugin (add the height of the footer to its value to create an offset)

Comment: @Johannes This question never used `<br>` tags at all. What makes you think that it did?

Comment: @JamesDouglas The code on his page (to which he supplied a link) contains/contained those <br> tags, and they were the reason for this behaviour (which didn't appear in the snippet of the question, so the OP asked to look at his original page)

Comment: @Johannes Ah, that makes sense!

Comment: Sorry, I have 9 reputation, so upvotes will be recorded but will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex;` for the parent `p` tag. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in your snippet seems to work ok. I'd recommend using `text-decoration: none;` on the `<a>`'s though.

```css
.social {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.social h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.social a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social a i {
  padding: 0px !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  font-size: 46px !important;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.fa-facebook-square {
  color: #4267b2;
}

.fa-facebook-square:hover {
  color: #365899;
}

.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #1da1f2;
}

.fa-twitter-square:hover {
  color: #1da1da;
}

.fa-linkedin-square {
  color: #0084bf;
}

.fa-linkedin-square:hover {
  color: #0073b1;
}

.fa-instagram {
  color: #d9317a;
}

.fa-instagram:hover {
  color: #bc318f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="social">
  <h4>Connect with me on below social channels:</h4>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/RealMahadev/" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fb"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/realmahadev" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/realmahadev" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/realmahadev/" target="_blank" itemprop="SameAs">
    <i class="fa fa-instagram instagram"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```